# SQL query, time span

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, where-clause

I am working on a script for keeping track of people who attend a workplace. I am to find who has been at the place during a time span.

It have to also find people who has been there even for a while during that time span.

Also those who has arrived after the time start and also left before end of the workday. Anyone who have been there at any time I will need to find using this SQL query.

I have the following. But it will just give me those who has been there from after the start time `($time_from)` , and left  before end time `($time_to)`.

```
$SQL_String = mysqli_query ($con, "
    SELECT * 
      FROM log 
     WHERE users_name = '" . $username . "' 
       AND login_time >= '" . $time_from . "' 
       AND logout_time <= '" . $time_to . "' 
     ORDER 
        BY dateandtime ASC
    ");
```

`login_time` and `logout_time` are the start and end times in the database, for the user. While `$time_from` and `$time_to` are the start and end time, as selected in the form.

If I search on these hours;

10:00 – 12:00

- The member who had these hours should be counted. 9:00 – 10:05
- The member who had these hours should be counted. 10:05 – 11:45
  The member who had these hours should be counted. 11:00 – 12:05
- The member who had these hours should be counted. 9:00 – 13:00

In short:

I need to find who have been at the work in a given time-span. No matter If they have been there all day, or arriving late, or leaving early – if they have been there within the times read from the form.

Can you help me with this problem??
Thanks!

Comment: All of the above. Plus https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You want any overlap  That would be:

```
select l.*
from log l
where l.login_time < $time_to and
      l.logout_time > $time_from;
```

The logic is pretty simple timeframe A overlaps with timeframe B if A starts before B ends and A ends after B starts.

Answer (score -1):

You have 3 cases:

- Person arriving in given time frame
- Person leaving in given timeframe
- Person arriving before, leaving after timeframe

Now combine to something like this:

```
where 
(arrival >= starttime AND arrival <= endtime) 
OR 
(departure >= starttime AND arrival <= endtime) 
OR
(arrival <= starttime AND departure >= endtime)
```

Oh and by the way: your sql is open to sql injection filterability. Never use variables directly in sql strings.

Comment: No. There's only one case.